# How to add spans to every word in paragraph of text?

Tags: javascript, append, nodes, html

How to append a span to every word in a particular document `div` ("text")? New to using `nodes` in `js`. Keep getting message,

> "object has no method append child..."

What am I missing? This is my code:

```
var y; 
var words; 

function get() {
    y = document.getElementById("text").firstChild.nodeValue;  

    words = y.split(" "); 

    for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        var newSpan = document.createElement('span'); 
        words[x].appendChild(newSpan); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first fetch the dom element you want to append the words to,

```
elem = documents.getElementById("#some_container");
```

Then append the words to it

```
words.forEach(function(w) { 
 var new_span = document.createElement('<span>');
 new_span.innerHTML = w;
 elem.appendChild(new_span);
});
```